# Javascript to Post Inside a Div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have this code bellow and I need it to make a post inside a div.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $(".loader").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // stop the link loading the URL in href
        $('#content').load($(this).attr('href'));
    }); 
});
</script>



<form method="post">

some random inputs and checkbox's goes here

<input type="submit" href="/consulta/consulta_produto.php" class="loader" value="Consultar">

</form>
```

When submiting, the javascript is sucessfully loading the consulta_produto.php inside a div called "content", however, I need to adapt the script to make it possible to POST too

Someone at other topic said to Use `$(".loader").parent("form").submit` instead of `$(".loader").click`, however i didnt understood what he meant, I tried changing it in a lot of different ways, but none of them worked

I researched a few topics about how to post with javascript, but I could adapt none of them to keep the function to load consulta_produto.php inside the div "content"

So I wonder, how can I adapt my javascript to keep loading consulta_produto.php inside content div while posting the data from some inputs and check boxs?

Comment: Sorry, but what you have isn't even close, it is a get request. Further more `href` is not a valid attribute for `input`. What you actually need is AJAX. There are many tutorials out there for that. You are already using jQuery, so a good starting point would be the documentation there: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ . The final example should get you started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to either:

1. Place all of your `<script>` code after the relevant HTML has been loaded, OR
2. Wrap it all in a `$(document).ready(function() {...});` to achieve the same effect

Then, instead of executing code at your inputs `click()` event, you can do it upon your forms `submit()` event. (This is basically what you mentioned someone told you in another topic). I changed your submit input to a submit button, doesn't really matter.

So, instead of loading the `href` attribute, you load the `action` attribute of the form itself into the div.

Of course you want to submit actual data along with the form - no problem. You just use an **AJAX** method. This is in order to stop the page from reloading.

First you do the `preventDefault()` to stop the usual page reload. Then you initialize the `$.ajax()` method.

- Data: The first parameter 'data' contains all the form data to pass
  along.
- Type: Represents the type of request (POST)
- URL: This is the    form action (/consulta/consulta_produto.php).
- Success: Finally, the    'success' parameter contains a function
  which loads it all into the specified `<div>`.

AJAX is essential when avoiding page reloads in PHP, play around with it!

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#form").submit(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({ //AJAX Method
            data: $(this).serialize(), //Gets data from form
            type: $(this).attr('method'), //Gets the method, in your case POST
            url: $(this).attr('action'), //Gets the form action
            success: function(r) {
                $('#content').html(r); //Loads data into div
            }
        }); //End of AJAX Method

        }); //End of form submit event
    });
    </script>
```

And here is your HTML:

```
    <div id="content" style="width:100%; height:500px; ">
    </div>

    <form id="form" action="/consulta/consulta_produto.php" method="post">

        some random inputs and checkbox's goes here
        <button type="submit">Consultar<button>
    </form>
```